# $ not available in onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload

I cant understand the error where $ is unidentified when using onload on my page. This is just as sample page I created where I need to call a function after loading the page.

```js
Jquery Code

$(document).ready(function(){
 alert("loaded");
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

</body>
    <script src="../Jquery/contact.js"></script>
    <script src="../Jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Jquery/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/default.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>



</html>
```

Comment: Move `contact.js` below `jquery.js`.

Comment: contact.js  should be loaded after loading jquery

Comment: also do we need jquery migrate plugin when you are using jquery 1,12?

Comment: hi Guys, thanks for the input. so basically I had 2 problems on this. I solved the first one by moving the contact.js to the bottom and remoing the migrate plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. It's invalid to put `script` or `link` tags as direct children of `html`, so it doesn't surprise me that it doesn't work correctly on at least some browsers. You need to put them in the `body` or `head`. The [**only** valid content of the `html` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element) is a single `head` element followed by a single `body` element.

   Standard guidance, for instance in the [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) is:

   - Put the `link` tags in `head`
   - Put the `script` tags at the bottom of `body`, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag
2. It looks like your `contact.js` file calls `$()` immediately (not in response to an event). If so, then `contact.js` must be **after** jQuery in the list of scripts, so that jQuery has been loaded when your code runs.

So:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/default.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="../Jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Jquery/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Jquery/contact.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Side notes:

- You might look at script and CSS combining and minifying, to avoid having a lot of HTTP requests.
- Consider adding `<!doctype html>` at the very top to ensure the browser is in standards mode (not quirks mode).
- Consider adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` at the top of `head` (ensuring that the file is indeed in UTF-8, or changing the "UTF-8" in that to whatever encoding you're actually using in the file).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the input. so basically I had 2 problems on this. I solved the first one by moving the contact.js to the bottom and removing the migrate plugin.